How to release/publish several versions of the application for each client
I have a website that is separated by React repo and ASP.NET repo. I want to have a base repos with the base features of websites. Then, with each client, they need different features and configurations. Can you propose a good way to make it work? I read a github doc about fork repos - https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/syncing-a-fork. My idea is that when I need new features for a client, I'll develop only on that client repo. In case that feature should become a base feature, I'll try to merge it to the base repo. But I am concerned that a lot of repo will be created and it will be hard to manage them.
My plan is to use the Azure static web app and Azure API management service to publish the repos. How about the docker? Please give me some advice. Many thanks
